# How to fix long pauses within calls to Python's XML tree parser?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

In a Python program I'm repeatedly calling `xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring` to parse self-contained XML documents ranging from 4k to 6MB each.  Most calls to the parser complete in under 1 ms.  However, after 17 hours of processing and the parsing about 11 million documents the process increasingly becomes intolerably slow, taking more than a minute and as much as five minutes to parse a single small (e.g. 14 kB) XML document. This pause repeats after every twenty thousand chunks. During the pause Python (version 3.7.3) isn't calling any system or library functions and takes up completely the CPU core it's running on.  An examination of the call stack shows the following functions:

```
#0  0x000000000050fcc0 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000005897df in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000518776 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000519fc5 in _PyObject_GC_New ()
#4  0x00000000005bcf6a in PyList_New ()
#7  0x00007ff88be4491e in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
#8  0x00007ff88be454bc in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
#9  0x00007ff88be42f8b in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
#10 0x00007ff88be43e7b in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
#11 0x00007ff88be47a38 in XML_ParseBuffer ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
#14 0x00000000005ccba1 in _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords ()
#16 0x000000000054653a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#17 0x000000000053f732 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName ()
#18 0x00000000005cd982 in _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords ()
#20 0x000000000054653a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#21 0x000000000053f732 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName ()
[…]
```

At the time the pauses start to occur the Python process occupies 12.1 GB of virtual memory with 8.7 GB resident on a machine that has another 60 GB of RAM available.   I find the memory consumption excessive, as I'm not keeping any data in memory: I write selected data from each document into an SQLite database.

I suspect the problem is related to pathologically inefficient memory management associated with Python or the XML parsing library. Any ideas on how to fix it? Could I somehow reset the XML parser state between calls or preemptively perform garbage collection before the heap's structure become intolerably convoluted? With a 17 hour wait to try each possible fix, I'd prefer to hear from somebody who knows a solution rather than try various possible fixes on my own.

Comment: It’s a rearchicture and more work for sure but saxparser based approaches dont mind large docs.  Not taking away from answers here, merely alternative.

Comment: Thanks @JLPeyret! I'm not parsing a large document. I'm parsing millions of moderately-sized documents. I'm afraid if this a Python memory management problem it might also occur with other approaches.